# How to create permalink with id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I create a permalink with an id for a new model?

E.g

```
animal = Animal.create(name: 'cool dog') #creates animal with id of 1 and name of dog

animal.permalink => "1-cool-dog"
```

How do you add the proper callback so that id is inserted? `before_save` or `after_save` doesn't work

```
after_save :update_permalink #or before_save

def update_permalink
  self.permalink = "#{id} #{name}".parameterize
end
```

What ends up happening is I get "cool-dog" instead of "1-cool-dog"

And I get why. It's setting an attribute without saving it on after_save. But doesn't work on before_save either because id hasn't been created on a new record.

Comment: Something you should think about is overriding the to_param method of your animal model instead of adding a permalink to your db. Rails will auto magically turn the permalink that starts with the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

You should use after_commit instead of after_save

> Both save and destroy come wrapped in a transaction that ensures that
>   whatever you do in validations or callbacks will happen under its
>   protected cover. So you can use validations to check for values that
>   the transaction depends on or you can raise exceptions in the
>   callbacks to rollback, including after_* callbacks.
>
> As a consequence changes to the database are not seen outside your
>   connection until the operation is complete. For example, if you try to
>   update the index of a search engine in after_save the indexer won’t
>   see the updated record. The after_commit callback is the only one that
>   is triggered once the update is committed. See below.

As I commented above you may want to simply override the to_param method of your Animal Model like this.

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
end
```

This will make all of your urls automatically like the permalink you are trying to create and you can still use `Animal.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't need to save the permalink to the database at all.

```
def permalink
  "#{self.id} #{self.name}"
end
```

This approach would add a permalink to the model by concatenating the id and name each time the permalink is read.